# Why was it so important for Hashem to create the 'mouth' of the ass

Tags: animals, creation, speech-talking, miracle, parashat-balak

We read in Balak that the ass 'spoke' to Bilaam. This was a special miracle that an ass could speak, made during the six days of creation.

Hashem doesn't make miracles for nothing. What is the great lesson we can draw from this that made it so necessary?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/talmud3/n0M7MQJFA5A for many similar types of questions

Comment: You question would be much improved if you would [edit] into it support for your claims (1) that an ass spoke to _Bil'am_, (2) that the miracle was created during the _sheshes y'me v'reshis_, and (3) that _Hashem_ doesn't make miracles for nothing.

Comment: *What is the great lesson* seems either too broad or primarily opinion based. I think that a simple "Why" would be a *much* better question

Comment: Different approaches to this can be taken. Some useful source material includes *Zohar* (*Balak* 201b, for a kabbalistic approach), *P'siktasa Zutrasa* (*Balak*), Rabbeinu Bechaye (*Bamidbar* 22:28), *P'ri Tzadik* (ibid.), *S'fas Emes* (ibid.), Alshich (*Sh'mos* 34:1-3), and Meiri on *Avos* (ch. 5). (Actually, a number of these sources complement each other).

Comment: Most questions have more than one answer. The torah is made up of 'pardes'. Your answer seems to include them all. Not everyone is capable of looking all this up. Perhaps you can give us some idea of what the answers are @fred

Comment: Perhaps the question would be better if:
1. You mention that in Avot is says the "mouth of the ass" was created just before twilight on the eve of Shabbat.
2. You ask why it needed to be created at that time, i.e. why couldn't the miracle have just occurred without that, or G-d have created this potential phenomenon when donkeys were first created.

Comment: I'm about to answer along the theme of what @Cashcow was hinting at. That focuses on the general concept of what "miracles" really are, as well as why this one was created specifically just before Shabbat. I don't know if that's the focus of your question, so I'm not answering until you can clarify your focus.

Comment: It is not the focus of my question but I would very much like to hear your answer since I also have my own. You can either ask another question yourself or ask CashCow to do it since I am restricted to asking more questions.  Or put it on my site which I hope you have visited. @DanF I could add many things to the question like how is this different to the talking fish I linked to, how is it Balaam wasnt at all surprised and fazed about hearing an ass talk and even arguing with her. I would have liked to add this too but this is not allowed here.

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3574/next-publication-project/3577#3577 I notice your post. I would very much like to contribute to such a publication @DanF. If you do make one you are welcome to use anything from my site.

Comment: See edit in my answer below which includes link to M.Y. question as to why these items were created just before Shabbat.

Answer (score 2):

[Rabbeinu Bechayei on Pirkei Avot 5:8](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9712&st=&pgnum=113) expands on the Mishnah citation that among the 10 things created during twilight prior to the start of Shabbat, is the mouth of the donkey that spoke to Bil'am.

He states that all 10 things in the list were created for the honor of Israel. The main idea to be learned is that the donkey doesn't speak on its own, but rather, that it is G-d who gives the donkey the power to speak. I.e., rather than viewing this as an unusual "miracle" and be surprised or "shocked" by it, Jews would understand that there is nothing too unusual or powerful for G-d to create, and a talking donkey is not unusual.

Take a close look at the wording of the Mishnah itself. It says ten **things** were created, not "ten miracles", as you have written in your question. Yes, we (not just you and I, but many of us) think of these ten items as "miracles" because we are not used to talking animals (i.e. - besides parrots & maccaws, etc. that, to some degree, can speak in "human" language). But, in fact, the Mishnah teaches us that these were part of creation, so at the point that it occurs, and when we read about them, we are not viewing them as unusual miracles, but part of G-d's plan.

Also, note, that this may explain why Bil'am doesn't seem surprised about his talking donkey. Perhaps he watched Shrek the movie, first ;-) Seriously, Rash"i, among others, explain that Bil'am was a prophet almost equivalent to Moses. So, granted, that this Mishnah was not written (though, it may have been orally transmitted by Moses, already), but, at the least, having a high, prophetic intelligence, Bil'am may have understood that a talking donkey was part of G-d's powers.

See [this M.Y. question / answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40944/5275) explaining the significance of why these 10 items were specifically created before Shabbat.

Comment: Thanks, If you look at your link you will also find an answer to my question which is the standard answer. It would also explain the talking fish. But that is not my understanding of Rabainu Bchayai that every animal has the power of speech. My own answer (in my style) is entirely different especially why Balaam wasnt 'fazed' by it speaking.

Answer (score 0):

The Avarbanel here explains that god did that to warn bilam and make him understand  that just as he can put whatever he wants in the ass's mouth , so he will do with bilam's mouth

Comment: Rabainu Bchayai quoted earlier says something similar.